# XMPP MUC Max Users

Tags: xmpp

I have a page that lists all of the public chatrooms and I am trying to have: 
total occupants / max users

IE. (05/10 People in room)

The Extended Disco Info Result ([Querying For Room Information](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html/#disco-roominfo)) returns the current occupants in the room, but does not show what the maximum occupant spots are.

How would I go about retrieving the Max Users for the room(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html), just below [example 10](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#example-10) is the text specifying allowed fields in the extended discovery result, which includes:

> ...any field defined for the muc#roomconfig FORM_TYPE can be included in the extended service discovery fields (as shown above for the "muc#roomconfig_changesubject" field).

So a server supporting this would return in the discovery result a field such as the following:

```
<field var='muc#roomconfig_maxusers' 
         label='Maximum Number of Occupants'>
    <value>10</value>
</field>
```

If your server doesn't return this, perhaps file a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

```
One can set the number of occupants in MUC's Configuration. Example 157 in XEP-0045
```

Using Stanza:

```
 <field var='muc#roomconfig_maxusers' 
         label='Maximum Number of Occupants'>
    <value>50</value>
</field>
```

---

Objective-C Code:

NSArray *fields = [newConfig elementsForName:@"field"];
for (NSXMLElement *field in fields)
{
    NSString *var = [field attributeStringValueForName:@"var"];

```
if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_maxusers"])
{
    [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
    [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"50"]];
}
```

[XMPPRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:newConfig];
}