# XMPP room max user limit

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am new to XMPP and read a few docs, but couldn't find the max user limit in a MUC? Is this configurable and if so what would be the max value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805102/xmpp-muc-max-users

Answer (score 0):

In case the post mentioned in the comment doesn't help you can view [this](http://mail.jabber.org/pipermail/jdev/2007-July/085053.html) mail thread.